# Robot.keyPress does'nt work for VK_ALT_GRAPH (Invalid key code)

Tags: java, keypress, keyevent, awtrobot

I'm working on a remoting app.(mouse - keyboard) I just showing fastly my issue...

It's working for 'A' or some basic characters.

```
    case "a":
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

But I did'nt make '@' character. My way is look like this.

```
 case "@":
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH);
```

I see the exception when I use VK_ALT_GRAPH;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid key code
at sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer.keyPress(Native Method)
at java.awt.Robot.keyPress(Unknown Source)
```

Is that a bug? How can I press '@' char? Also like this, I cant do these ;
$ , # , ? , [ , ] , {, } , ' , * ...

Comment: *"How can I press '@' char"* Press `VK_SHIFT`, Press `VK_2`, release `VK_2`, release `VK_SHIFT`

Comment: I've tried this. But It's make it ' character.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you're using a keyboard different from mine. What key does the "@" character reside with?

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is very old, but nobody gave a correct answer and after practicing I went with the solution.

That is my keyboard:

[image]

and for press @ or # you must to do it:

```
            bot.keyPress(VK_CONTROL);
            bot.keyPress(VK_ALT);
            bot.keyPress(VK_3);

            bot.keyRelease(VK_CONTROL);
            bot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
            bot.keyRelease(VK_3);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need this:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```